# search through file for data and create new txt file with just that data

Tags: bash, awk

I have a txt file that is an output from a machine with a bunch of writing/data/paragraphs which are not used for graphing purposes, but somewhere in the middle of the file I have the actual data that I need to graph. I need to search the file for the data and then print the data to a txt file so I can graph it later.

The data in the middle of the file looks like this (with each data file potentially having different amounts of rows/columns and numbers are separated by spaces):

```
<>  1   2   3   4   5   6   etc.

A   1.2 1.3 1.4 etc.

B   0.2 0.3 0.4 etc.

C   2.2 2.3 2.4 etc.

etc.
```

My thinking so far was to grep to '<>' to find the first line (grep '^<>' file) but I'm not sure how I would account for the variable amount of rows/columns when trying to find them. Also, I am using awk to loop over all .txt files in the directory and print to a new outfile so I can do multiple files at once (so maybe I can do this search/printing in awk as well?).

Edit:

--input/expected output file--

input file

```
This is the data

Here are some paragraphs

<>  1   2   3  

A   1.2 1.3 1.4

B   0.2 0.3 0.4

C   2.2 2.3 2.4

more paragraphs

more paragraphs
```

output file:

```
<>  1   2   3  

A   1.2 1.3 1.4

B   0.2 0.3 0.4

C   2.2 2.3 2.4
```

Using awk to do this to multiple txt files in a directory.

Comment: Is there a termination token/tag? I mean, `<>` tells you where the data you want begins. How do you determine where it ends?

Comment: sal - thats another problem, there is no termination token (i have no control of the output file setup).

Comment: james - im not sure if I understand your question fully, but I think to answer you I am trying to get the data exactly as it is represented in the original file into a new file with just the data and no 'other stuff'.

Comment: Sure. Please post some data and expected output.

Comment: But the data you are interested match a pattern like shown in your example with no other *interfering* lines. In other words, is it possible a line of data such as `ZXWY 5.2 2.3 1.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk. It looks for `<>` or decimal number (`[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`) in a record. If that's not enough, maybe you could try to expand that decimal number testing part to test for 3 numbers, something like: `(/ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+){3}/`

```
$ awk '/<>/||/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/' foo
<>  1   2   3
A   1.2 1.3 1.4
B   0.2 0.3 0.4
C   2.2 2.3 2.4
```